# Give file link in place of absolute path in fs.createReadStream();

Tags: node.js, fs

I've a code like this

```
const fileData = fs.createReadStream('Google Sheet Link');
```

The error I am getting is this.

This is probably due to `fs` trying to read from an absolute path, rather than directly from the URL.

The path, it is taking is "Directory to which file is located" + "Google sheet link"

I only want to open google sheet link in the createReaderStream Path.

I've hidden the google sheet path due to privacy reasons.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The createReadStream() method is an inbuilt application programming interface of fs module which allow you to open up a file/stream and read the data present in it.

```
fs.createReadStream( path, options )
```

Parameters: This method accept two parameters as mentioned above and described below:

- path: This parameter holds the path of the file where to read the file. It can be string, buffer or URL.
- options: It is an optional parameter that holds string or object.

Now, To avoid paths issues, it's recommended to use path.join, like:

```
const path = require('path');

const pathGoogleSheet = path.join(__dirname, 'Sheet name');
const readableStream = fs.createReadStream(pathGoogleSheet);
```

Here, you're creating a path to the google sheet referring to the current directory of the script stored in global variable called __dirname.